# My ip gets transformed when stored to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, ip

I am writing a script that gets the visitors IP, removes the dots off it with explode, stores the IP without dots in the database, and then gets it and echoes it.
But, my IP gets really messed up when I store it into the database.

[HERE IS THE CODE!](http://hastebin.com/hibeteragi.php)

EXAMPLE: My ip is `178.175.35.205` , without dots: `17817535205` , but when gone through MYSQL, I can even see it on PhpMyAdmin, is transformed to `2147483647`.

UPDATE: Turns out everything was fine, but I was using `INT` except for `BIGINT`. That fixed it.
I am now using ip2long and long2ip.

Comment: What do you mean by *"messed up"*?

Comment: I need to see the 'messsed up' IP

Comment: Don't store it as integer in the db, problem solved.

Comment: @N.B. , what should I store it as ?

Comment: ^ Listen to N.B. (although E_p's solution & INET_ATON() etc. can be a valid choice, most people usually store this as a char for good reasons).

Comment: Why would you remove the dots?? This seems like a bad idea. Example: 123.45.12.34 and 123.45.123.4 would both give the same IP if you don't keep the '.' (123451234) Just store the IP as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel

use `http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php` and `http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php`
functions to do conversions.

It would also validate it for you

```
$ipToStore =  ip2long($ip);
if (false !== $ipToStore) {
    // Store your ip
}

// Read DB
echo long2ip($ipFromDB);
```

Make sure in db to use `BIGINT` to store it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types

Comment: Yeah, tried that too, I get the same results. The exact same string.

Comment: Make sure that in DB row you store in is `bigint` as `int` is not enough

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake. Wasn't storing it as bigint. Updated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Store the IP as a string

BENEFITS:

2) You can leave in the "."

... AND ...

3) You can accomodate either IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses

IMHO..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the integer representation you are using is larger than what can be stored in an `INT` column in MySQL.  In PHP you can use the `ip2long` function to convert an IP address to a proper 32 bit integer.